# Проблема с картами

Tags: openstreetmap, карты

Есть десктопное приложение для мониторинга транспорта предприятия с возможностью отображения растровых карт, построения маршрутов и т.д.. Требуется вместо карты, установленной по умолчанию, отображать карты из OpenStreetMaps.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, удобный инструмент, желательно .dll.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос немного сумбурный...

В каком виде есть приложение - исходники или проприетарное?

Если проприетарное (есть только исполняемый файл/инсталяшка, но нет исходных кодов) тогда в общем случае сделать ничего нельзя. Есть маленький шанс, что именно под данное приложение есть плагин который такое сделает или в кофигах можно прописать путь к тайлам... Но так как это скорее всего какой-то самопис то нифига этого там не предусмотренно. (Если что-то приличное - желательно бы знать название приложения).

Ну, как вариант, можно перед приложением засунуть прокси-сервер, который будет конвертировать запросы к тайлам с родного сервера, на ОСМ. Если по-умолчанию приложение использует гугл-карты - это вполне реально. Если яндекс - нет - у яндекс своеобразная методика пересчета координат в тайлы (используется немого другая, ГОСТвая, формула).

Если софт в исходниках проблем не вижу. Нужно найти место формирования тайла и поправить путь. Любой программист это сможет для вас сделать. Если изначально юзали не гугл - нужно смотреть формулы пересчета, и возможно их править. Это задача на порядок сложнее; но в общем тоже решаемо.

Answer (score 0):

если десктопное приложение заточено на использование готовых растровых карт, то скорее всего возможности это изменить нет.
как вариант - разработать свое веб-приложение в дополнение к десктопному, которое используя тот же сервер навигации будет отображать информацию по машинкам на любой он-лайн картоплатформе.